# I can't use my SharedPreferences in another activity

Tags: android

first one is:

I have a setting activity and when I set my settings and I got back to Main-Activity My settings have not been applied.

Second one is:

I have a SharedPreferences in my setting activity for saving my setting.
but I don't know how can I use that when I start my app for the first time because my Shared-Preferences isn't build up yet. My SharedPreferences is in my Setting activity not in Main Activity. How can I do that?

I'm sorry if it's stupid question:)
please help.

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement here.  Your Android code needs to be vigilant and cannot assume that shared prefs would always have state.

Comment: Can you add your code for storing and retrieving the SharedPreferences?

Comment: i haven't problem with my SharedPreferences. i have problem with structure of SharedPreferences that don't allow to use SharedPreferences in other Activities

Comment: SharedPreferences can be use in activity you want. you need to create the SharedPreferences object in activity where you want to use .

Comment: you can use sharedPreferences in any activity you want , can you explain your problem so we can help you?